# How to remove more than one whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hello guys I currently have a problem with my `preg_replace` :

```
preg_replace('#[^a-zA-z\s]#', '', $string)
```

It keeps all alphabetic letters and white spaces but I want more than one white space to be reduced to only one. Any idea how this can be done ?

Comment: http://dk1.php.net/trim

Answer (score 2):

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```

[From Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

\d, \w and \s

Shorthand character classes matching digits, word characters (letters, digits, and underscores), and whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks). Can be used inside and outside character classes.

Answer (score 1):

The character type `\s` stands for five different characters: `horizontal tab` (9), `line feed` (10), `form feed` (12), `carriage return` (13) and `ordinary space` (32). The following code will find every substring of `$string` which is composed entirely of `\s`. Only the first `\s` in the substring will be preserved. For example, if line feed, horizontal tab and ordinary space occur immediately after one another in a substring, line feed alone will remain after the replacement is done.

```
$string = preg_replace('#(\s)\s+#', '\1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace(array('#\s+#', '#[^a-zA-z\s]#'), array(' ', ''), $string);
```

Though it will replace all of whitespaces with spaces. If you want to replace consequent whitespaces (like two newlines with only one newline) - you should figure out logic for that, coz \s+ will match "\n \n \n" (5 whitespaces in a row).

Answer (score 0):

try using `trim` instead

```
<?php
$something = "   Error";
echo $something."\n";
echo "------"."\n";
echo trim($something);
?>
```

output

```
  Error
------
Error
```

Comment: What about `"Err   or"`?

Comment: in that case you will need regula expressions, since is not white extra space, is just miss spelled word.

Comment: It's not the fact that words are split up, it's the fact that OP is trying to remove whitespace inside a string, for example two spaces between words.

Answer (score 0):

Question is old and miss some details. Let's assume OP wanted to reduce all consecutive horizontal whitespaces and replace by a space.

Exemple:

```
"\t\t \t  \t" => " "
"\t\t   \t\t" => "\t \t"
```

One possible solution would be simply to use the [generic character type \h](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) which stands for horizontal whitespace space:

```
preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $text)
```